# Angular 5 ngSubmit @Output fires twice

Tags: events, output, components, angular5

**CUSTOM COMPONENT**

```js
// ...

@Output() submit: EventEmitter < any > = new EventEmitter();

// ...

onFilterSubmit($event): void {
  this.submit.emit($event);
  this.formData = {
    minDate: new Date().toISOString(),
    maxDate: new Date().toISOString()
  };
}
```

```html
<form (ngSubmit)="onFilterSubmit(formData)">

    <!-- -- -->
    <button mat-button
        mat-raised-button
        [disabled]="reqsForm.form.invalid" 
        type="submit"
        color="primary">
        {{labels.submit}}
    </button>
</form>
```

**OUTER COMPONENT**

```js
// ...

onFilterSubmit($event): void {
  console.info("FORM SUBMIT", $event);
}
```

```html
<custom-component (submit)="onFilterSubmit($event)">

  <!-- -- -->

</custom-component>
```

**OUTPUT**

`FORM SUBMIT > Object`

`FORM SUBMIT > Object`

Comment: I had the same issue. Removing `(ngSubmit)` from custom component helped me to get rid of multiple call problem.

Comment: @AKJ Glad to hear that!! Cheers! ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason why this was happening is that an event called "submit"
is catchable already from outside the **custom component**.

I solved by changing the custom event name to **filterSubmit**

Note also that the `type submit` on the button - in this use case - is virtually useless, since as default **one** button in a form will be of type submit.